# Change SVG color when importing from file

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a bunch of `SVG` files on the website and would like to easily import them and change their color (they are all just black) to fit the context. I know that it is possible by doing something like:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="fill: red">
<path d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path>
</svg>
```

Here it is as simple as doing `fill: red`, but I have not found any way of using the `<svg>` tag with the link, and `<img>` doesn't support that property.

The `svg` all follow the same pattern, but I can edit them if it is necessary:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 88.65 122.88" style="enable-background:new 0 0 88.65 122.88" xml:space="preserve"><style type="text/css">.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}</style><g><path class="st0" d="M45.65,3.62v... you get the idea ...115.63c06.46z"/></g></svg>
```

What would be the correct way of approaching this issue without saving a separate `SVG` file for every possible color or inserting the data into each page in a form of `d= "path data"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the inline fill and wrap the svg in an object with a class. Then target the SVG as a child of that object.

```css
.pacman-blue svg {
  fill: blue
}

.pacman-green svg {
  fill: green
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="pacman-blue">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path>
</svg></a>

<a href="#" class="pacman-green">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path>
</svg></a>
```

I also use the USE tag to embed the SVG even using the same SVG for multiple symbols.

**USE:**

```
<svg class='icon icon-pacman'><use href='icons.svg#icon-pacman'></use></svg>
```

**SVG FILE:**

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-pacman" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<title>pacman</title>
<path d="M30.148 5.588c-2.934-3.42-7.288-5.588-12.148-5.588-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16s7.163 16 16 16c4.86 0 9.213-2.167 12.148-5.588l-10.148-10.412 10.148-10.412zM22 3.769c1.232 0 2.231 0.999 2.231 2.231s-0.999 2.231-2.231 2.231-2.231-0.999-2.231-2.231c0-1.232 0.999-2.231 2.231-2.231z"></path></symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: [Add a ``<load-file>`` native Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) to load the **external** SVG file, and you are done.

Comment: But you are still using the data directly, and I am rather interested in how to import an svg from file

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Could you give a working example for my situation, please? I have tried examples from the link and they don't work on my website. The article is overly complicated and thus I am afraid I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @user9102437 I have updated my answer to include using the **use** tag to embed the SVG

Comment: @user9102437, sorry, if the article/code is too complex, you have some learning to do. If you had mentioned the SVG ``use`` tag in your original question, I wouldn't have posted the link. It can be done, just not in the 8 lines of code of the Web Component.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I said complicated in a sense that it is a cluttered trash.  You say it cannot be done in 8 lines of code, while the article clearly advertises it right at the beginning. If you don't have a working solution, don't making "smart" responses in a form of a link to the wikipedia. I would actually advise you to learn a thing or two from `imvain2` because he actually did what was asked and literally used one single line of code.